# Joomla 3.8.1 и CAPTCHA - reCAPTCHA v2

Tags: joomla, captcha

Здравствуйте.
Установил Joomla  3.8.1  и CAPTCHA - reCAPTCHA v2 на локальном сервере OpenServer.

Ввел публичный и секретный ключ, на страницы контактов где установлена CAPTCHA - reCAPTCHA v2, активировал плагин.

Выбивает: **Ошибка: неверный домен ключа.**
Можете помочь, где ошибка?

Comment: И откуда вы взяли ключи для reCAPTCHA? какой домен написали при генерации ключей ?

Comment: Ключи взял с https://www.google.com/recaptcha, а при генерации указал localhost.

Comment: Если установили Localhost. проблем не должно быть, ещё раз проверьте, правильно ли скопировали ключи для Localhost